# c++ class method auto template parameter automatic deduction

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible for a class method to be called somehow and automatically deduce templated arguments?

I'm trying to create an object with a create class method that calls a private constructor.
I'm doing so in order to make sure the created instance is allocated on the heap.

The class in templated and I'd like the user not having to know the types (can be complicated with rvalue reference to lambdas).

Here's a toy example of what I'd like to achieve (I know the constructor is public here):

```
template <typename T>
class hello
{
public:
    hello(T t){}

    static std::shared_ptr<hello<T>> create(T t)
    {
        return std::make_shared<hello<T>>(t);
    }
};

template <typename T>
auto create_hello(T t)
{
    return std::make_shared<hello<T>>(t);
}

void test_hello()
{
    auto h1 = hello(3);  // ok
    auto h2 = std::make_shared<hello<int>>(3);  // ok
    auto h3 = create_hello(3); // ok
    auto h4 = hello<int>::create(3); // ok
    auto h5 = hello::create(3);  // Compile error: 'hello' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
}
```

Is there a way to invoke the static create method and having the template parameters automatically deduced like when calling the constructor directly?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not currently possible. There are only a few contexts in which the template arguments of a class can be [deduced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction):

> any declaration that specifies initialization of a variable and variable template, e.g.
>
> ```
> hello h(3);
> ```

> new-expressions, e.g.
>
> ```
> auto h = new hello{3};
> ```

> function-style cast expressions, e.g.
>
> ```
> auto h = hello(3);
> ```

and from c++20:

> the type of a non-type template parameter

---

In this expression:

```
hello::create(3)
```

the template argument needs to be deduced, since it's not specified, but none of the above contexts apply, since there is no rule for deduction of a template parameter from the invocation of a static member function.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up two different things:

1. Constructor template deduction and
2. function template deduction.

Whereas `auto h1 = hello(3)` works since, it makes use of constructor template deduction, but since `create` is not a constructor, the template parameter cannot be deduced from the parameter.

To solve that, you have to source out your `create` function:

```
template <class U>
static std::shared_ptr<hello<T>> make_hello(U t)
{
    return std::make_shared<hello<U>>(t);
}
```

Edit:
If you want have the constructor private, just friend the function:

```
template <typename T>
class hello
{
    hello(T t){}

public:
    template <class U>
    friend std::shared_ptr<hello<U>> make_hello(U t);
};
template <class T>
std::shared_ptr<hello<T>> make_hello(T t)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<hello<T>>(new hello<T>(t));
}
```

Comment: In the code I wrote, I did use an external create function "create_hello". The problem with this approach is that it will not work if the constructor is private.

Comment: you can declare the make function as `friend`